Pdf Box Content Node Transfer
I'm working on a PDF accessibility and I don't have much knowledge about Java, so I asked ChatGPT to make a code for pdfbox. The script should delete all "Span" tags but retain its child (leaf node), but the code only works properly if Span's child tag is not a leaf node. If it is a leaf node the child tag becomes blank. I appreciate any insights regarding this. Thanks.
private static void processElement(PDStructureElement element, List<Object> parentKids) {
    List<Object> kids = element.getKids();
    List<Object> newKids = new ArrayList<>();

    if ("Span".equals(element.getStructureType())) {
        parentKids.addAll(kids);
    } else {
        for (Object kid : kids) {
            if (kid instanceof PDStructureElement) {
                processElement((PDStructureElement) kid, newKids);
            } else {
                newKids.add(kid);
            }
        }
        element.setKids(newKids);
        parentKids.add(element);

Tried reconstructing the PDF structure and the Java code.

Your code is not self working (how is processElement() called?) and please link to a PDF with this. One may have to delete parts of the content stream as well.
